# GTM & Optimize : JS Variable is undefined but in console it works well

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I'm trying to show the Google Optimize variant in Google Tag Manager.

I tried to implement it by "Custom JavaScript Variable":

```
function() {
  var property = window.keys(gaData);
  var experiment_nr = window.keys(window.gaData[property].experiments);
  var experiment_value = window.values(window.gaData[property].experiments).toString()
  if (experiment_value == "") {
    return "0"
  } else {
    return experiment_value
  }
}
```

This is the result of it:

[image: Custom JavaScript Variable Result]

Then I tried to test my code with a 5 sec delayed trigger:

[image: GTM HTML Tag]

And this is the result of the DevTools JS console:

[image: DevTools Console result]

As you can see, the console does not accept it with GTM but accepts it when I type it manually in.

Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple.

Google Optimize uses a cookie called `_gaexp`.
There, you get a string summing up the Google Optimize experiment ID as well as the version at the very end:
`GAX1.2.wHL2IJUnSg2n8PB4iQH66w.18362.1`

All I had to do was to create a new **variable reading the cookie**:

1. New variable
2. 1st Party Cookie with the cookie name "_gaexp"

You can of course get the cookie name with JavaScript by simply calling `Cookies.get('_gaexp')` from the DevTools Console (to check if the cookie value is right)

The `_gaexp` value has to be manipulated to isolate the variant:

1. New variable
2. Custom JavaScript
3. Add the following code:

```js
function (){
  if ({{GA_Optimize_Variable}}=='undefined'){
    return '0'
  } else {
    return {{GA_Optimize_Variable}}.charAt({{GA_Optimize_Variable}}.length-1)
  }
}
```

The `_gaexp` is not existant when Google Optimize leads your traffic to the original variant of the website. Therefore, a if statement is needed.

Finally, you can use your variable in Google Analytics events and/or dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using **dataLayer** instead of window object.

Comment: I saw in your second post that you solved using the dataLayer variables so I would say that the problem is solved. Well!

Comment: Well, I used the cookie variable rather than the Data Layer. It is stored locally and easier to read for Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Excellent alternative solution. However, it is necessary to recover the data with the functionality and syntax of the Tag Manager, not directly with the window object